# Formula for correlation with if-condition in Python

Tags: python, correlation

I have a dataset, for instance, like this:

```
| A | B |  C |
| - | - | -  |
| 2 | 6 | 10 |
| 3 | 7 | 15 |
| 1 | 4 | 24 |
| 6 | 2 | 20 |
```

So I need to find a correlation between columns with a condition for each C (if C>15, if C>20 etc.) and find for what C correlation is max?

Is there a way to do this with some formula and if-statement? Because there are more than 5000 rows and I don't get how to do it quickly...

Thanks in advance for the help to a beginner :)

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of what sort of output you want?

Comment: Well, I can do this code: `df.loc[df['C']>20].corr` to find correlation only when C>20. But I have to check correlation for all C...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the formula for correlation, you need 2 sums: (x-ux)(y-uy) and (x-ux)²(y-uy)². If you're allowed to use the average of all the rows (even though you're computing correlation for a subset of rows), then you could sort the rows and go through them one by one, adding to the sums and recomputing the correlation as you go along.

Pseudocode:

```
rows.sort_by("C")
means = calc_means(rows)
diff_sum = 0
square_diff_sum = 0
max_correlation = 0
max_C = 0
for row in rows:
    diff_sum += (row["A"]-means["A"])*(row["C"]-means["C"])
    square_diff_sum += (row["A"]-means["A"])^2 * (row["C"]-means["C"])^2
    correlation = diff_sum/sqrt(square_diff_sum)
    if correlation > max_correlation:
        max_correlation = correlation
        max_C = row["C"]
print(max_correlation, max_C)
```

If you're NOT allowed to use the "global" means, then you can compute all the means (the means for C<10, the means for C<15, etc) in one pass, but I think you might need to make another full pass for each mean to find the correlations. Though there might be a clever way to do it in one pass.